# Prevent material flicking in Blender animations

Tags: animation

Is there a way to prevent the material flicking, as you can see in the following video?

I understand that it's most likely from objects being too close to one another, but they are modeled so one object covers another, by 1 or 2 inches.  That is, they are not coplanar.

Is there a setting one can use to fix this problem?

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlqKx5hdk3U

edit:
blender file: https://gitlab.com/openingdesign/highland_haven/-/blob/837de31cb8ca0d78a9e1fe44440ddcc3a845d066/Models_and_CAD/BlenderBIM/Highland_Haven.blend

Comment: there's a problem somewhere, it can be the camera clipping values or Z fighting, hard to say, maybe share your scene (just keep one house)?

Comment: Hi, here's the blend file: https://gitlab.com/openingdesign/highland_haven/-/blob/837de31cb8ca0d78a9e1fe44440ddcc3a845d066/Models_and_CAD/BlenderBIM/Highland_Haven.blend

Comment: So it looks like you have overlapping faces in your roofs, what does it give if you remove or move up a bit a roof that is overlapping?

Comment: I increased the clipping start distance, and it 'seems' to have corrected it!

Comment: maybe also move up the roofs to avoid z fighting as well

Answer (score 2):

You have overlapping faces in the roof, it creates a *Z fighting* effect, if you want to keep these roof layers, at least move them a bit to create a tiny gap:

[image]